# Checking for the existence of a javascript var inside an array that may or may not exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to check to see if something exists in an array, let's say the array `arr` is:

```
{"targeting":{
     "key1":"1",
     "key2":"2"},
 "session": "1234"
}
```

I want to check to see if arr.targeting.key1 exists so I do:

```
if (true === !!arr.targeting.key1)
```

This is true if it exists, but what if `arr` is empty? Then I get an error:

> cannot read properties of undefined, reading 'key1'

What is the simplest way to check for the presence of `arr.targeting.key1` that will just return false if `arr.targeting` or `arr` themselves are undefined?

Comment: You have no arrays, only objects.

Comment: So check if the object exists before reading its properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
if (arr?.targeting?.key1)
```